# Removing \n in a list and starting new item where \n was

Tags: python, list

This is my `print(lst)` at the moment:

```
['Observation date:2021-04-25 11:00\nReporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34\nName:Robert Kniewasser\ne-mail:rkniewasser@petzl.com\nProfile ID:15444', 'Place:Schrocken Elm Plan\nRegion:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen\nLocation:47.64627°N / 14.19269°E\nElevation:2160m\nIncline:35°\nAspect:N']
```

I would like to make the data in the list into different items so I can store them in a variable.

Example:

- `Observation_date = "Observation date: 2021-04-25 11:00"`
- `Reporting_date = "Reporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34"`

So I need to make a new item / insert a ', ' as a replacement for every \n

I would like to be able to just to:

```py
Observation_date = lst[0]
Reporting_date = lst[1]
```

Comment: Why not just use `split()`?

Comment: split() only works for strings right? or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Andy Yes, it works only for string, but inside the list, you indeed have string values.

Comment: lst.split("\n") does not work for me though :(  "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: @Andy You have to split the string, not the list. If the list you've shown in the example is called `lst` you have to access the string in the list. So it's `lst[0].split('\n')`.

Comment: @Andy of course it's only for strings, I meant to split the string, not the list itself, I assumed you would recognize what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the split method.

```
data = ['Observation date:2021-04-25 11:00\nReporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34\nName:Robert Kniewasser\ne-mail:rkniewasser@petzl.com\nProfile ID:15444', 'Place:Schrocken Elm Plan\nRegion:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen\nLocation:47.64627°N / 14.19269°E\nElevation:2160m\nIncline:35°\nAspect:N']
new_data = data[0].split('\n')
print(new_data)
```

#result

```
['Observation date:2021-04-25 11:00', 'Reporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34', 'Name:Robert Kniewasser', 'e-mail:rkniewasser@petzl.com', 'Profile ID:15444']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way with `split` and `list-comprehension`,

```
data = ['Observation date:2021-04-25 11:00\nReporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34\nName:Robert Kniewasser\ne-mail:rkniewasser@petzl.com\nProfile ID:15444', 'Place:Schrocken Elm Plan\nRegion:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen\nLocation:47.64627°N / 14.19269°E\nElevation:2160m\nIncline:35°\nAspect:N']
result = [i.split('\n') for i in data]
lst = [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]
Observation_date = lst[0]
Reporting_date = lst[1]
print(lst)
print(Observation_date, Reporting_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the one and only string in the list at the newline character and then split the resulting elements at the `:` to create a dictionary.

```
data = ['Observation date:2021-04-25 11:00\nReporting Date:2021-04-26 19:34\nName:Robert Kniewasser\ne-mail:rkniewasser@petzl.com\nProfile ID:15444', 'Place:Schrocken Elm Plan\nRegion:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen\nLocation:47.64627°N / 14.19269°E\nElevation:2160m\nIncline:35°\nAspect:N']
result = dict(entry.split(':', 1) for entry in lst[0].split('\n'))
print(result)
```

This will give you the following dictionary:

```
{'Observation date': '2021-04-25 11:00', 'Reporting Date': '2021-04-26 19:34', 'Name': 'Robert Kniewasser', 'e-mail': 'rkniewasser@petzl.com', 'Profile ID': '15444'}
```

Now with `print(result['Name'])` you get `Robert Kniewasser`.